# C# DOT NET Application crash when accessing through nvidia quadro 600 gpu mode- nvd3dum.dll crash

Tags: c#, dll, crash, driver, nvidia

32bit Application developed in c# with VLC player 32bit dll components getting crashed. Below provided the crash details and system information. Please give me an quick solution.

System information:
OS:Windows 10 pro 64bit
Processor: I7-7700 CPU @ 3.60 GHz
Graphics card: Nvidia Quadro 600
RAM: 32GB
System Model: Precision Tower 3620 Dell
Bios: 2.8.1
Directx: 12
Inbuilt Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 630

Source
Cyphy VideoMonitor Client

Summary
Stopped working

Date
‎27-‎12-‎2018 16:37

Status
Report sent

Description
Faulting Application Path:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Cyphy Client Applications\VMS_VideoMonitor.exe

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   VMS_VideoMonitor.exe
Application Version:    1.3.9.4
Application Timestamp:  5c23a950
Fault Module Name:  nvd3dum.dll
Fault Module Version:   23.21.13.9125
Fault Module Timestamp: 5aab746d
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   007ef1e4
OS Version: 10.0.17134.2.0.0.256.48
Locale ID:  16393
Additional Information 1:   2beb
Additional Information 2:   2beba6fb4680d73a8c78ca7c24ccdb46
Additional Information 3:   5e24
Additional Information 4:   5e242fda7d18813327ab5a22faeed05c

Extra information about the problem
Bucket ID:  aaf891aea295151974dcff40831e65f8 (1503357028177700344)

Comment: what line in your application causes the crash and please show that code block to enable us to help you

Comment: Hi Welcome to Stack Overflow! But we can't help you just by looking at some error messages, we also need to look at your code (so we know how this crash can be recreated.)

Answer (score 0):

To analyze crashes always use Microsoft's crash dump analysis tool. You can download it here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/2580960/debug-diagnostics-tool-v1-2-is-now-available

You can never tell the reason behind a crash from the source code alone, this tool helps you identify possible reasons for the crash.

Here is a good tutorial: https://stackify.com/using-windbg-to-analyze-net-crash-dumps-async-crash/